# How to load image from URL into shadow-box?

Tags: image, shadowbox

I'm using shadow-box to display images in my project, I did the integration for the css and js files and called the function:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../libraries/shadowbox-3.0.3/shadowbox.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../libraries/shadowbox-3.0.3/shadowbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Shadowbox.init();
</script>
```

here are the codes to get the `src` attribute and `wrap` the images by links with `rel='shadowbox'`

```
$('#display_article #core_art').each(function(){
        var src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        $(this).find('img').wrap("<a href='"+ src +"' rel='shadowbox'></a>");
    });
```

the problem is, when I click on the image, shadowbox is appear, but the image does not. what seems to be the problem ?

Comment: are you getting correct link in src ?

Comment: yes, I've tried to `alert(src)` and it done successfuly, also the I've tried to add diffrent images with diffrent size, when the shadow-box starts, the black wrapper takes the image size form but no image.